# Proper way to send JWT token via http client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-6.0

I am looking for a way to send the JWT token in the header via the HTTP client but could not figure out the options, and below is the code in the startup file.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ..........

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = $"{Configuration["ApiClientAuth:Authority"]}/v2.0";
            options.Audience = Configuration["ApiClientAuth:ClientId"];
            .....
            options.SaveToken = true;
        });   
        
        //Using this middleware delegating handler to send the token but wondering whether this is the correct approach.
        services.AddTransient<TokenHandler>(); 

        var stitchingServices = new List<StitchingService>{ new (....), new (....)};

        stitchingServices.ForEach(x => services.AddHttpClient(x.Name, (sp, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(x.GraphqlUrl);             
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenHandler>());
         
         // For the above HTTP clients, I need to send a JWT token via the HTTP client header 
        var hotChocolateServices = services
                                   .AddGraphQLServer()
                                   .AddAuthorization()                                                                     
                                   .........

        if (WebHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            hotChocolateServices
                .AddInstrumentation()
                .AddApolloTracing();
        }
    }
```

Below is the middleware delegating handler code

```
public class TokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    public TokenHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) => this.accessor = accessor;

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var accessToken = await accessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        request.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Is this approach delicate, or is there any straightforward approach to sending the token via HTTP client? The access token is getting null when I debug this delegating handler.

Comment: You might want to look at the [HeaderPropagation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HeaderPropagation) nuget package, which implements exactly what you want. There's a sample showing how to use it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4094430163458ac10f42736daba09bdec4d0dffc/src/Middleware/HeaderPropagation/samples/HeaderPropagationSample/Startup.cs).

Comment: @Eduardomacedo, I thought only be adding this  `services.AddHeaderPropagation(options =>
            {
                options.Headers.Add("Authorization");
            });`  would sufficient if we want to send the auth token in header

Comment: You need to also add the middleware in the `Configure()` method (i.e. `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) { app.UseHeaderPropagation() }`) and add the header propagation to the HttpClient on configure services: `services.AddHttpClient(...).AddHeaderPropagation()`

Comment: So could you please let me know, Is that sufficient to propagate the header to HTTP client

Comment: Still, it is not working, getting an error like `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your configuration then. I made a small sample [here](https://github.com/edujtm/HeaderProp.Sample) that shows the header being propagated, maybe it will help you out.

Comment: Thank you, I am just looking at your project, and is this mandatory if we want to propagate only authorization `app.MapGet("propagate", async (IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) => {
  var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("header-test");

  var result = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com/");
  var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  return Results.Ok(content);
});`

Comment: Maybe look at using RestSharp package?